# Cómo hago para quitar las llaves {} y meter el contenido en []

Tags: javascript

Estoy obteniendo unas coordenadas de una polilínea:

```js
var polyline2 = L.Polyline.fromEncoded(encoded);

console.log(polyline2.getLatLngs());
```

cuyo resultado arroja:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero necesito meter la latitud y la longitud de todos los resultados en array individuales **[]** separados por **,** en el array **array_box**

Es decir que cada uno quede así:

```js
let array_box = [

[123456789, -123456789],
// ETC...

];
```

Intenté con:

```js
var array_box = [];


for (var i = 0; i < polyline2.getLatLngs().length; i++) {


    array_box.push([polyline2.getLatLngs()[i]]);

    console.log(array_box);

}
```

Tal parece que cada uno queda dentro de **[]** pero siguen las **{}** y no sé cómo separar la latitud y la longitud y agregar la **,** despues de la longitud

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Qué debería hacer?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que necesitas hacer es recorrer todo el arreglo en el que están tus objetos, y dentro de cada recorrida, declarar un arreglo nuevo al que le hagas push las 2 propiedades en el orden que las requieras, algo así

```js
const array_box = [];

polyline2.getLatLngs().forEach(element => {
    const tmpArr = []
  tmpArr.push(element.lat)
  tmpArr.push(element.lng)
    array_box.push(tmpArr)
})
```